# Where are translations for drop-downs?

Tags: translation, drop-down

In some places, e.g. the configuration of scheduled reminders, there are drop-down selection boxes that sometimes are translated.

We have a Swedish side and the particular drop-down I'm looking at is in Swedish. However, if I change the UI language to English, that is still in Swedish.
[image]

I'm a translator for the Swedish internationalisation so I looked for the strings in Transifex, but found nothing. [UPDATE: the text is in Transifex, but the translation did not match, that´s why did not find it...]

I also know of "Administer->Customize Data and Screens->Dropdown Options" but those are not for this type of drop-downs.

So where can I find those translations so that I can modify them?

[UPDATE: maybe this is about when drop-down texts are populated, cached etc. ...]

Comment: You don't have anything in Admin > Customize Data & Screens > Word Replacements that could be affecting this? Which select are you looking at in particular? The English text definitely exists. I wonder if there is something set up on your site specifically that overrides this text.

Comment: No Word Replacements. I'm looking at the Recipient drop-down when editing a scheduled reminder for Cases. The Swedish options seems wonky, and although the help text seem to miss mentioning it, the first option must be Activity Assignee. And that text is translated in Transifex, but it does not change when I turn language back to English leading me to think that it was stored somewhere else. Are drop-down texts cached somehow so I need to restart the web server when changing language? (Didn´t try that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That drop-down is pulling options from the activity_contacts option group. So it sounds like your option group is in Swedish and doesn't have English labels available.

Comment: RIght. I now remember that if you do a localized install according to the documentation there is a script that will run in the localization step. That presumably updates all the option groups and possibly other stuff in the database. And, again, presumably, that script pulls those translations from Transifex. But obviously they never get updated. So actually it is that last bit, getting updated translations into the database, especially considering that they might have been locally modified.

Comment: Yes, that's the trouble, not sure how getting the localized option group labels is supposed to be done, over my head. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: @thoni56 For an install where you only select one language at a time, there is https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/fixoptiontranslations which is what it sounds like you're thinking of. For full multilingual, which is a bit fragile but people use it, then for each option value there's an "ABC" icon to the left of the field that lets you translate in all the languages enabled.